# How to enter into passive mode with Apache SSHD

Tags: java, ftp, apache-mina, sshd

I have a following code that creates remote `ChannelSubsystem` (FTP client) using Apache Mina SSHD:

```
org.apache.sshd.client.channel.ChannelSubsystem c = session.createSubsystemChannel("sftp");

int authState = ClientSession.WAIT_AUTH;

while ((authState & ClientSession.WAIT_AUTH) != 0) {

    System.out.println("authenticating...");

    authFuture.addListener(new SshFutureListener<AuthFuture>()
    {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(AuthFuture arg0)
        {
            System.out.println("Authentication completed with " + ( arg0.isSuccess() ? "success" : "failure"));
        }
    });

    authState = session.waitFor(ClientSession.WAIT_AUTH | ClientSession.CLOSED | ClientSession.AUTHED, 0);
}

if ((authState & ClientSession.CLOSED) != 0) {
    System.err.println("error");
    System.exit(-1);
}

OpenFuture openFuture = c.open().await();
```

How can I via `ChannelSubsystem` send a command to remote FTP site to enter to passive mode?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use the passive mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting using the SSH/SFTP, not the FTP.

There's nothing like the active/passive mode in the SFTP.

---

The active/passive mode is distinguished with the FTP protocol, because it uses a separate data connection. In the active mode, the server initiates the data connection. In the passive mode the client initiates the connection.
See my article on the [FTP connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) for details.

There's no separate data connection in the SFTP, hence no reason for the active/passive mode.

Comment: Martin, thanks a lot for your valuable help. Do you know why when I am writing a Buffer inside of DefaultSftpClient.getOut() stream, the DefaultSftpClient.getIn() stream is still null..client is connected. I thought that the issue is the passive mode, now I dont know

Comment: You are welcome. Please start a new question. This is Q&A site, not a discussion forum.